# MySQL - Drop temporary table when exception occurs in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and not able to figure out how to drop all temporary table created within stored procedure when any exception occurs. The problem is when error occurs on first call of stored procedure and if I try to call procedure again it throws exception like "temporary table already exists".

I can use DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF Exits [tablename] syntax and than create temporary table again, but i think its not the best solution. Is there any way to drop all temporary tables when any SQL exception occurs in the procedure?

Following is what I am trying to drop temporary tables but I am getting error

> Error Code: 1051 Unknown table '[databasename].testtable'

Code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`*****`@`%` PROCEDURE `Test`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR sqlexception
    BEGIN
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE TestTable;
    END;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TestTable AS SELECT * FROM
    (
        (SELECT 1 AS AccountID)
        UNION
        (SELECT 2 AS AccountID)
    ) bt;


    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        TestTable;

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'test';


    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE TestTable;
END
```

Comment: @e4c5 this not real store procedure. just a sample to explain what i am trying. My actual store procedure has different logic and if exception is thrown by any statement between create and drop than how to drop temporary table created in procedure.

Comment: @e4c5 sample code is for suggestion given by Dag Sondre Hansen. He suggested a to use handlers to drop temporary table when exception occurs but if throws "table not found" error.